# php match cells from 2 databases and pull out cell info

Tags: php, sql

I have my users database and my person database

In the USERS database I have the following cells

```
ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PERSON_ID
```

In the PERSON database I have the following cells

```
ID, FIRSTNAME, PHONE
```

I would like to SHOW out the PHONE from PERSON DB based on the PERSON_ID from the USERS DB
(the ID in the users db and person db is not the same so therefore i need to match the ids thru USERS.person_Id to get the phone)

This is how far I am - without luck though... nothing shows:

```
$query = "SELECT person_id FROM user WHERE person.id=$user_person_id";
$result = mysql_query($query); $line = mysql_fetch_object($result);
echo "Phone: $line[$phone]";
```

Comment: $query = "SELECT person_id FROM user WHERE person.id=$user_person_id";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $line = mysql_fetch_object($result);
   echo "Phone: $line[$phone]";

This is how far i am - without luck tho... nothing shows

Comment: Moved comment into question for better readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT `id`, `person`.`phone` FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `person` ON `users`.`person_id` = `person`.`id` WHERE person.phone IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, if I understand your question very well, then SQL JOINS will help you. Here I will be using left join. But try to read more about joins.

```
 $sql = "SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`firstname`, `users`.`lastname`, `person`.`phone` FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `person` ON `users`.`person_id` = `person`.`id`";

 $query = $mysql_query ($sql);
 $result = $mysql_fecth_assoc ($query);

 echo 'Phone: ', $result['phone'];
```

Here are your errors:

1. From your comments you were fetching the results as an object yet displaying it as an array. $line = `$mysql_fetch_object($result);`
2. You were using a variable as the array key. `$line[$phone];`

Try these new codes. I hope it should work.

Comment: thanks but how will i be able to show the 'phone' cell? (sorry, im a noob so need a answer so i understand how to show the cell)
Tried the code but didnt work...

Comment: run the query (i.e $sql ) alone in your phpMyAdmin or Mysql workbench

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$sql = "SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`firstname`, `users`.`lastname`, `person`.`' at line 1

Comment: SELECT `id`, `person`.`phone` FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `person` ON `users`.`person_id` = `person`.`id`

this gave me what i want but i need to remove the NULL results...

Comment: SELECT `id`, `person`.`phone` FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `person` ON `users`.`person_id` = `person`.`id` WHERE person.phone IS NOT NULL 

tadaaaa :)

Comment: then use `FROM users JOIN person ON users.person_id = person.id